# Does $T\mathbb{C}P^n$ have one-dimensional subbundles?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Does $T\mathbb{C}P^n$ have one-dimensional subbundles when $n>1$? It seems like Chern classes doesn't give any obstacles for this, because of $c(\mathbb{C}P^n)=(1+a)^{n+1}$ and we can conclude only that if such bundle exists then it have to be isomorphic to tautological line bundle of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ (because of $(1+a)$ divides $(1+a)^{n+1}$).

Comment: As far as I can tell, at least for $n=2$ it does. In this case you can get examples by clutching over $\mathbb{C}P^1$ and the 4-cell.

Comment: @Tyrone thank you, and what about holomorphic subbundles?

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't comment. I'd also check to see if my claim is useful to you. I'm sure someone more knowledgeable should be able to comment on the case for general $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $E$ is a smooth complex vector bundle and $F$ is a smooth complex subbundle, then we can equip $E$ with a hermitian metric to construct $F^{\perp}$ and obtain the isomorphism $E \cong F \oplus F^{\perp}$.

Every line bundle on $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(k)$ which has first Chern class $c_1(\mathcal{O}(k)) = ka$, so if $T\mathbb{CP}^n$ has a line subbundle, we see that $T\mathbb{CP}^n \cong \mathcal{O}(k)\oplus E$ where $E$ is a complex vector bundle of rank $n - 1$.

In particular, if $T\mathbb{CP}^2$ has a line subbundle $\mathcal{O}(k)$, there is another line bundle $\mathcal{O}(l)$ such that $T\mathbb{CP}^2 \cong \mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(l)$. Note that

$$3a = c_1(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = c_1(\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(l)) = c_1(\mathcal{O}(k)) + c_1(\mathcal{O}(l)) = ka + la = (k + l)a$$

and

$$3a^2 = c_2(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = c_2(\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(l)) = c_1(\mathcal{O}(k))c_1(\mathcal{O}(l)) = (ka)(la) = kla^2$$

so $k + l = 3$ and $kl = 3$. But there are no such integers $k$ and $l$, so $T\mathbb{CP}^2$ does not admit a line subbundle.

As for the general case, we have the following theorem from Glover, Homer, & Stong - *Splitting the Tangent Bundle of Projective Space* (Theorem $1$ (ii)).

> If $n$ is even, $T\mathbb{CP}^n$ does not split into a non-trivial Whitney sum of complex subbundles.
>
> If $n$ is odd, $T\mathbb{CP}^n$ splits only into a complex line bundle and its complement.

Comment: It seems like define line subbundle of $T\mathbb{C}P^3$ is the same as define operator $T : \mathbb{C}^4 \to \mathbb{C}^4$ with property $<v,Tv>=0$ where $<?,?>$ - standart scalar product. And it seems like $T(e_1) = e_2, T(e_2) = -e_1, T(e_3) = e_4, T(e_4) = -e_3$ fits.